# How to redirect user to registration page in IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4

I have implemented app security based on [6th step of quick start "Using ASP.NET Core Identity"](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/6_aspnet_identity.html), so login/register forms implemented at auth. authority side. Now for any secured page user redirected to login page on auth. authority. On my asp.net core mvc based client app i have login / register links in header. How can i redirect a user to registration page from client site to auth. authority site ?

Comment: I have the same question.  I also have a sign-in link in the menu/header, and likewise need to trigger the oidc login without actually trying to go to a secure page. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47294846/how-to-trigger-login-for-identityserver4-without-accessing-secure-page-in-the-mv

Comment: Did you guys solved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend creating a single link for unauthorized users in your client application: `Register or Login`. Rather than sending the user somewhere specifically for registration, move the choice of login or new registration into the Identity Server login page.

You *always* want to send the user to Identity Server within the context of a login flow. If you allow third-party IdPs (Google etc) this also makes more sense to a new user: from a single page they can create a new account with a third-party IdP *or* register a new local account. (When you process an external login, compare the IdP email address against your user database. If the email address is new, the user is new. If the email address is on file from another IdP, you probably want to cancel the login and warn the user by email that they chose the wrong IdP.)

From there, you're just doing redirection within Identity Server to complete registration and login, and everything will work as long as you're careful to keep track of that return URL.