# How to trigger login for IdentityServer4 without accessing secure page in the MVC app?

Tags: asp.net-identity, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.0

In the docs
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/quickstarts/3_interactive_login.html

it says "**Trigger the authentication handshake by navigating to the protected controller action**".  This would be by simply accessing any action in your MVC site with [Authorize].  After signin, this would redirect to the page they were trying to access, not to the page they last visited (which is good, expected behavior).

Great. But what about this scenario?

1. User is in some anonymous part of the site.
2. User clicks "Sign in" from the menu
3. User Signs in at Identity server
4. User is redirected back to the anonymous (un-secure) page they were **last visiting** (could be one of many) BUT is now signed in should she decide to later hit an [Authorize] page.

**How do we initiate oidc Sign-in without hitting a secure page in MVC?**

Comment: You might be able to use [`ChallengeAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.challengeasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0) for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's just standard ASP.NET Core authentication - call

`HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("name_of_oidc_scheme");`

You also want to pass in an `AuthenticationProperties` object where you can set the URL where you want to end up after authentication.

Comment: Thanks, that's it.

On a related note, how would you get IdentityServer to render the registration page instead of sign-in for exactly the same scenario (assume login/register links from main menu). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689212/how-to-redirect-user-to-registration-page-in-identityserver4)

Comment: Guys, according to this DOC: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhttpcontextextensions.challengeasync?view=aspnetcore-2.0
This method is available for the ASP.NET Core version 2.0. I'm still on the 1.1. Do you know how to do it here?

Also could you please provide the details on WHERE do you use this line? Just place it in the Home\Index?

Comment: I have found the call `await HttpContext.Authentication.ChallengeAsync("oidc");` but it redirects to the IDSRV Login page